# Binding boolean to IsEnabled

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

### Edit:

I added the INotifyPropertyChanged like ASh suggested, but still it doesn't work 100%, but I will ask that in an other question.

I realised that I got the HasChanged wrong and changed it to !=

### Updated Original Post

I got a class called **Document**

```cs
public class Document : INotifyPropertyChanged
{                  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }             

    private string oldId;
    public string OldId
    {
        get { return oldId; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { 
            id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("HasChanged");
        }
    }

    private string path;
    public string Path
    {
        get { return path; }
        set { path = value; }
    }

    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get { return id != oldId; }
    }

    public Document(string id, string path)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.oldId = id;
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

I got a List of **Documents** in my WPF code behind, **items** is an ItemsControl in my Form.

```cs
AddItem("a", "b");
AddItem("b", "b");
AddItem("c", "b");
AddItem("d", "b");
```

...

```cs
private void AddItem(string key, string value)
{
    items.Items.Add(new Document(key, value));
}
```

My WPF looks as follows:

```cs
<ItemsControl x:Name="items" AlternationCount="100">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox 
                    Text="{Binding Id}"

                    PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"></TextBox>
                <Button 
                    Grid.Column="1" 

                    IsEnabled="{Binding HasChanged}"
                    Content="Ok"

                    Click="ButtonOk_Click"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As you can guess, I want to enable the Button, when the text in the tb has altered from the original text.

Problem is that the binding on IsEnabled doesn't work.

What has to be changed to get it working?

Or is there a better way to get the button enabled after a change, keep in mind that I can't directly access the button from the code behind, because the ItemControl is generating them on-the-fly, based on my template.

I don't want to work with a ViewModel because the app is very small and wouldn't profit from it.

Comment: Your boolean doesn't notify its changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) in `Document` and raise `PropertyChanged` event when `HasChanged` changes (in `Id` setter), binding for `IsEnabled` should update